# Django Social Auth Facebook Valid URL callback

Tags: python, django, facebook, ssl

Since facebook does not allow URL requests from insecure (http) site to access it . I added http://example.com/oauth/complete/twitter/ and same for google they worked just fine . Now i tried to do same for facebook . I have the ssl certificate for the my site. I referred some questions here but it left me more confused .

**in my settings.py :**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'account.authentication.EmailAuthBackend',
)
```

**my urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls')),
    url(r'^oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social'))
]
```

i have added 
https://example.com/oauth/complete/facebook/  in  facebook's app but after i clicked on login with facebook it show invalid url .

Comment: question is not clear @Roy

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all. You need to ask an actual _question_ if you want to get any sort of help here; just telling us that you are confused doesn’t help at all.

Comment: i am sorry i am newbie here , please see the new updated post .

Comment: What error? Be precise, quote verbatim. _“i have added […] in facebook's app”_ - also a bit too vague to know what you actually did; show screenshots or explain what settings you made and where in detail.

Comment: **Warning
Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://** Now i have the ssl certificate integrated in my site .      https://humbusy.tk/account/login/?next=/account/